# Create a LINQ Expression with GroupBy and Dynamic Select

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say I want to make the following query into an expression such that the rollup property (Rent in this example) can be chosen at runtime.

```
public record Person(string LastName, string FirstName, decimal? Rent, decimal? CarPayment, DateTime DateOfBirth);
List<Person> persons = new List<Person>
{
    new Person ("Smith", "Joe", 1200.00M, 315.23M, DateTime.Parse("1/1/1957 3:53AM")),
    new Person ( "Smith", "Joe", 1500.00M, 0.00M, DateTime.Parse("1/1/1987 3:53AM")),
    new Person ( "Jones", "John", 2500.00M, 432.51M, DateTime.Parse("3/1/1958")),
    new Person ( "Smith", "Eric", 3000.00M, 290.00M, DateTime.Parse("5/1/1959"))
};

var group = persons
    .Where(p => p.LastName == "Smith")
    .GroupBy(g => g.FirstName)
    .Select(
        x => new
        {
            First = x.Key,
            Count = x.Count(),
            Rollup1Name = "Rent",
            Rollup1Value = x.Sum(x => x.Rent),
         }).ToList();
```

This is what I have so far:

```
IQueryable<IGrouping<string,Person>> groupQuery = persons
    .Where(p => p.LastName == "Smith")
    .GroupBy(g => g.FirstName).AsQueryable();

var l = BuildSelect<Person>(groupQuery, "Rent");
var list = l.ToList();


internal static IQueryable<object> BuildSelect<T>(IQueryable<IGrouping<string, T>> groupQuery, string rollup1)
{
    Type elementType = typeof(T);
    ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(elementType);
    Expression propExpression1 = Expression.Property(param, rollup1);
    // Wrap the expression body in a compile-time-typed lambda expression.
    var lambda1 = Lambda<Func<T, decimal?>>(propExpression1, param).Compile();

    IQueryable<object> l = groupQuery.Select(
        x => new
        {
            First = x.Key,
            Count = x.Count(),
            Rollup1Name = rollup1,
            Rollup1Value = x.Sum(lambda1),
        });
    return l;
}
```

This works. The resulting list has the expected groups. Now imagine that I do the same thing  against a table of Person in a SQL Server database. The ToList() throws an exception.

Expression of type 'System.Func`2[Person,System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal]]'
cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[Person,System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal]]]' of method 'System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal] Sum[Person](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Person], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[Person,System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal]]])' (Parameter 'arg1')

I've read where LINQ to SQL just can't compile certain expression trees. Is there anything I can do? If I have to hard-code the lambda with all possible values (as you might guess, the class we are actually using is much more complicated than Person), it will result in a lot of switch statement hacks.

Comment: Your mistake is calling `Compile`. `Queryable.Sum` takes an `Expression<Func<T,decimal?>>` not a `Func<T,decimal?>`. Remove the call to `Compile` and try again. Effectively you are trying to execute `decimal? propFn(Person p) { return p.prop; } ... x.Sum(propFn);` which will error out similarly.

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't compile. Remember, this all works for the LINQ in-memory case. The same code fails using Entity Framework Core SQL Server.

Comment: That is to be expected. What error message do you get when it doesn't compile? What is the type of the `rollup1` property?